# WCF Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority in iis

Tags: iis, ssl

I have created two wcf application and its working fine in my local iis. Now i hosted that application in production server. I got the error message. Can any one help me to solve this.

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'win-cmahasuzlr7:444'.

Comment: try posting some of your code of web config related to bindings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to Enable SSL for your Production server IIS.
Here are the steps:

1. IIS -> Sites -> Default WebSite -> Right Click -> Edit Bindings
2. Check if https is alredy there or not.
3. if Https  binding is not there, then add One binding for HTTPs
4. Use type = 'HTTPS', PORT : 443, SSL : Choose SSL Certificate.

Comment: Have you tried this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741994/ssl-wcf-could-not-establish-trust-relationshop?rq=1

Comment: No, Shall i try this?.

Comment: Yes, You can try this.